# How to create page with left sidebar In magento 2.1.15?

Tags: magento-2.1, cms-pages, custom-block, sidemenu

I want to create page or block with sidebar. if I click customer service then I want to see customer service info etc.

[image]

2nd Image :
[image]

3rd Image:
[image]

Comment: you can create a cms page and set its layout to 2 Columns left

Comment: I did, but I want to display all brands, customer service and sizing charts on left side.

Answer (score 0):

in order to have custom layout you need to follow below steps :

**Step 1 :**
Create **layouts.xml** file in **Magento_Theme** of your theme and paste below code in this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="customer_services">
        <label translate="true">Customer Service Page</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

**Step 2 :**

create **customer_services.xml** file in **Magento_Theme/page_layout** folder of your theme and paste below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="column main col-md-10"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="col-sidebar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-2" before="main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.serices.menu" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">customer-serices-menu</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customer.serices.block2" after="customer.serices.menu">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">customer-serices-block2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**Step 3 :**

in admin Create CMS static Blocks **customer-serices-menu** and **customer-serices-block2** and add content what you want to show on left sidebar ( you can add as many blocks as many you want just add block code with id in layout file ).

**Step 4 :**

Now finally create a cms page for customer services and assign **Customer Service Page** layout to that page and it will show content with left side bar.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response, I tried this code but i want if i click Customer service then I can see Customer service info or sizing charts have different info.

Comment: you can add that info in cms block how to manage it.

Comment: Can you explain me please in detail?

Comment: could you update your question with design layout you want to implement. as per your question you have to create a menu block and seprate page for each menu item. all pages should have Customer Service Page layout and you can setup content accordingly in each page.

Comment: Please check my update question. I want to display every sidebar have different info.

Comment: yes, you have need to create cms pages and assign Customer service page layout to all these pages. and each page will have sidebar with menu and content ( i.e brands , size charts etc what you want to add )

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I created customer service, sizing charts, brands and customer service pages. but I didn't understand how can I assign Customer service page?

Comment: in admin , go to cms pages and click on any page, scroll down to bottom of page there you will find Design tab. click on that and there you will see "Layout" select list. choose "Customer Servie Page" and save that page. check this screen shot https://prnt.sc/l772cq